# How to add to wpf references to another app, which had been written in powerbuilder

Tags: c#, wpf, powerbuilder

I have my wpf application, which starts some Process():

```
         Process process = new Process();
         process.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\t.exe";
         process.Start();
```

The Path @"c:\t.exe" can change.  How can I add a t.exe to  my project.

t.exe had been written in powerbuilder.

Answer (score 0):

The third line in your code snippet is missing a 's', I am pretty sure it should be:

process.Start();

Comment: In my wpf I have process.Start();

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know , along with **PBL** files you can definitely add **DLL** and **PBD** file in the libraries list of your target but never thought executable file could be added in a project that way. If your **EXE** file will be shipped with your actual project then you might consider using **Install Shield**. If this is not what you mean then please explain what do you mean by adding external **EXE** to a PowerBuilder project.